# Cannot install getkey module - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pip

There is a part in my python program in which i need to start a timer after the user hits any key. After some brief research i figured the getkey library would be the best fit for me.
But when i tried installing it via pip, it did not go well.
It just kept saying

*UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 499: character maps to <undefined*>

I then proceeded to try and clone it from github. I've got the folder, but once I install the setup, the same error pops up, just a different position.

*UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 876: character maps to <undefined*>

As I'm a beginner and have never encountered such dificulties with installing a library before, I ask for your advice.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you installing it? What is the command you are using?

Comment: pip install getkey.

Comment: or git clone https://github.com/kcsaff/getkey
cd getkey
python setup.py install

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.